# React server rendering, getting the HTML to the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to setup a simple app where I use React server rendering.

React 0.14.8, Express 4.13.4.

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const myApp = React.createFactory(require('./app/components/app.jsx'));

// ...express/handlebars setup stuff here

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(myApp());
    res.render('home', { content: html });
});
```

My `html` variable contains the markup, however it's escaped and the browser shows the HTML.

I know about `dangerouslySetInnerHTML()`, however I really don't want to have to use that. It's named that for a reason.

So I'm left thinking that there must be something I'm missing here. As server rendering is quite a big feature of React, and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML()` is discouraged, the two don't really feel like they should be used together.

What am I missing..?

Can someone provide a really basic, bare-bones example of React server rendering..?

Comment: Could you share what your myApp returns as html? That could also help the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was confused (it happens)... The HTML returned from `renderToString()` was actually ok, it was handlebars that was escaping the HTML.

In my Handlebars template file I changed `{{content}}` to `{{{content}}}` as per the docs: http://handlebarsjs.com/ (HTML Escaping).

The browser now renders the HTML as HTML instead of showing the HTML.

I feel I owe an apology to the `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` method.

I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the only way to inject `innerHtml` when rendering, unfortunately, is by using that dreadfully named `dangerouslySetInnerHTML()` function. Basically it's asking you to really think about it before you do it. A nice example is written out here: https://camjackson.net/post/server-side-rendering-with-react

Comment: Any time, thanks for adding the answer as well. Typically it happens indeed with templating engines, as per the example in the facebook documentation. upvotes are appreciated ;)